# Facebook sdk is compiling on my IOS device, but no my simulator

Tags: ios, facebook, compiler-errors, facebook-sdk-4.0

I've downloaded the Facebook SDK, and gotten it to work on the simulator to post from my app, but it won't even compile on my device.

```
 clang: error: no such file or directory: '/Users/justking14/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Descover-fqkbngyllggoxkcskmhhzgmkffxe/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libPluginFacebook.a'
 clang: error: no such file or directory: '/Users/justking14/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Descover-fqkbngyllggoxkcskmhhzgmkffxe/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libPluginProtocol.a'
```

libPluginFacebook.a and libPluginProtocol.a are in red in the Link Binary with Libraries, and when I remove them it still won't compile saying

```
 ld: file is universal (4 slices) but does not contain a(n) armv7s slice: /Users/justking14/Desktop/IR/cocos2d/plugin/plugins/facebook/proj.ios/sdk/FacebookSDK.framework/FacebookSDK file '/Users/justking14/Desktop/IR/cocos2d/plugin/plugins/facebook/proj.ios/sdk/FacebookSDK.framework/FacebookSDK' for architecture armv7s
 clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The FacebookSDK you use doesn't have machine code for the  architecture `armv7s`

That architecture WAS top of the line but now, apps mostly only use armv7 and arm64

---

Change your app build settings to only use those architectures (just use the default)
[image]